# Difference between functionName() vs functionname without parenthesis?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I use this, it doesn't work:

`document.getElementById('gid').onmouseover = functionname();`

But the following does work:

`document.getElementById('gid').onmouseover = functionname ;`

Could someone explain why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('gid').onmouseover = functionname
```

Here you assign your `onmouseover` which function will work. It will try to execute this function when `onmouseover` event will be fired. You pass only reference of your function.

```
document.getElementById('gid').onmouseover = functionname()
```

This first executes your function, because you call it (look at `()`) and returns `something`. After it your `onmouseover` tries to execute that `something`, which in your case I think is not a function.